# Use Java commons-httpclient with cacert, cert and key extracted from .pfx

Tags: java, ssl, curl, apache-commons-httpclient, jks

I have a .pfx file on input.

I extracted CA certificate, client certificate and key from it using following commands:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in input.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out client-cert.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in input.pfx -out ca-cert.pem -nodes -nokeys -cacerts
openssl pkcs12 -in input.pfx -nocerts -nodes -out client.key
```

Now I'm able to execute following request using curl:

> curl --cacert ./ca-cert.pem --key ./client.key --cert ./client-cert.pem -i -X POST --data-binary '@./my-data.txt' https://my-target.url

Now I would like to execute same request in Java using commons-httpclient

As far as I got it, I should convert my keys to "keystore.jks" and "truststore.jks" and use them as follwoing:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
   .loadTrustMaterial(new File("truststore.jks"), PASS.toCharArray())
   .loadKeyMaterial(new File("keystore.jks"), PASS.toCharArray(), PASS.toCharArray())
   .build();

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
    .setSSLContext(sslContext)
    .build();

HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://my-target.url");
post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("my-data.txt"))));
client.execute(post);
```

Is there any simpler way to pass certificates to POST ?
If not, what are correct way to converting my .pfx to .jks?

I tried

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore input.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

but end up with

> java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key

Comment: (1) your extract commands are mixed up; it should be `-nokeys -clcerts` for `client-cert.pem` and `-nokeys -cacerts` for `ca-cert.pem` (2) httpclient+core uses JVM default keystore and if you are reasonably up to date then **in 8u60 up the default can read PKCS12 directly** (3) if not, that `-importkeystore` is correct as long as you use the same password for the output (jks) as was used on the input (p12) (because the key pw is retained even if the store pw is changed)

Comment: Yes, thanks Dave, I mixed extract commands when I was changing filenames to post the question. In reality I did it right.
I figured out that I can just load pfx file as "PKCS12" keystore.
However I faced with "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" issue, that forced me to import ca cert to java security\cacerts.

Is there any simpler way ?

Comment: The CA for the _server_ cert, which might be the same as for your client cert or different, must be in your client's truststore (as trusted or private-leaf); if you use the default which is JRE/lib/security/cacerts and the server CA is not one of the established/public CAs distributed in cacerts then you must add it to cacerts -- but the `.loadTrustMaterial` call in your posted code _should_ use truststore.jks and NOT cacerts. Didn't it do so? What is in truststore.jks?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yes, thanks, I solved the problem by converting ca cert to JKS and loading using '.loadTrustMaterial'.

Answer (score 2):

Final solution was to load pfx file directly and trust certificates there.

```
final KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

try (FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File("file.pfx"))) {
    store.load(stream, PASS.toCharArray());
}
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
    .loadKeyMaterial(store, PASS.toCharArray())
    .loadTrustMaterial(store, TrustSelfSignedStrategy.INSTANCE)
    .build();
```